# How to restrict access to unwanted sites?

Tags: web-browser, firewalls, access-control

I use Ubuntu 13.10. I tried to used OpenDNS to restrict some websites. Unfortunately, I couldn't do that. I use AirStream 1200 USB modem to access WiMax internet. OpenDNS setting didn't work for me at all. Any alternatives to OpenDNS or any methods to secure my web browsing. I want solution that can't be easily hacked.

Comment: OpenDNS is a reasonable choice to achieve your objective of secure web access. Perhaps should you add details about your setting problems with OpenDNS.

Comment: @danielAzuelos Whenever I add domain of OpenDNS in IPv4 setting, I am unable to access internet. So, I can't use that setting.

Comment: I advise you to start another question about your need for `OpenDNS` trouble shooting, because you are on a right path.

Comment: @danielAzuelos I don't think, I need openDNS now. Your suggestion worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

I advise you to install [squid](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid).
It is a highly customisable web cache providing many configuration possibilities to protect of most of the attack web servers.
I'm using it to protect my network of add web servers, spying web servers,
any web servers without a DNS name, and many other sorts of attacks.

I'm testing many a priori filtering, and most of them are successfull:
when checking afterward the blocked web server I often discover a well
of malware.

Comment: My comment is that if @Habi hasn't been able to configure the client to properly use OpenDNS, it will (probably) be even harder for him to configure Squid properly! :)

Comment: I'm afraid you are right :). But for the OQ (and other readers) `squid` seems better suited than `OpenDNS`, under total contral for who wants to learn.

Comment: @scuzzy-delta After configuring my computer as per instruction provided in OpenDNS site, I was unable to connect to internet and evenmore, I tried to apply second option(i.e. configuring router). But, alas, I'm using modem to connect to internet.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to add the site to the /etc/hosts file but instead of adding its IP address you use any other IP. For example 127.0.0.1. This will always resolve the site name to this IP address. I hope I did understand your question.

Comment: This method won't scale well with the number of bad web servers. Moreover, some dirty web servers will use URL with an explicit IP address.